# MD5 Encrypt all the password in a table

Tags: php, mysql, md5

I have a database table called user where I have some columns. One of these columns is the user password.

This password is not encrypted, what I have to do now is grab automatically all the users and all the passwords in that table, encrypt them, and update the table with the new encrypted passwords.

What can I do? Using a PHP loop? Or what?

I am a little bit lost here..

Could you please provide a working example?

So I select the Passwords from the Table

```
$query="SELECT * FROM users";
$ar=mysql_query($query) or die("Error selecting accounts: ".mysql_error());
$ac = mysql_num_rows($ar);
while($arow = mysql_fetch_array($ar)) {
$password = $arow['Password'];
}
AND.......
```

After that I am totally lost.

Could you help me?

Thanks

Comment: It's impossible to do this because md5 is not encryption.

Comment: md5 is a hash that cannot be decrypted

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Enter this code to phpMyAdmin SQL query page. First login in phpMyAdmin, then select DB and table and then click "SQL". Then you need to enter this in the field and submit:

```
UPDATE users SET password = MD5(CONCAT(password, user_id))
```

**EDIT**

The OP wanted actual PHP code:

```
$query = "UPDATE users SET password = MD5(CONCAT(password, user_id))";
$ok = mysql_query($query);
```

Can't get any clearer than this. You'd have to make sure that the password field is big enough to store md5 hashes. Remember that md5 hashes are 32 characters long.

Comment: And with a salt: `UPDATE users SET password = MD5(CONCAT(password, user_id))`

Comment: Yes, use salts! Thanks arnaud. You have to remember that you used salts though. =)

Comment: Note that if you run this query twice, you've permanently lost all passwords.  And if you run this query, you'll have to change any client code that uses the password column to expect the MD5 hash instead of the real value.

Comment: No. I need to do that with PHP. This is for a package upgrade of one of my web applications. So many different customers will have to do this, and it should be very very simple. IS there a way to do it with PHP? Thanks

Comment: @DiegoP it's a query you can run from PHP. Don't you understand it? That's a question of exceptional stupidity. Poor customers

Comment: The answer is now edited. I can't be more explicit than that. If you still need help. Please do consult the PHP manual regarding MySQL functions. And accept the answer or comment otherwise why it is not what you need

Comment: @Andomar: Yes. You will lose the plaintext password but it is very dangerous to store plaintext passwords in databases. And based on the phrasing of the OP's question, it was assumed that the PHP code will be modified to accommodate md5 passwords.

Answer (score 0):

DiegoP asked way to do this with PHP, and here it comes (for some reason I could not add comment there..)

```
$db    = Do database connection here;
$query = "UPDATE users SET password = MD5(CONCAT(password, user_id))";
$doit  = mysql_query($query, $db);
```

**EDIT:** If want to loop it use

```
<?php
$q = "SELECT * FROM users";
$s = mysql_query($q, $connection);

for ($i = 0; $i < mysql_num_rows($s); $i++) {
$uid = mysql_result($s, $i, "user_id");
$pass = mysql_result($s, $i, "password");
$s2 = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET password = MD5(CONCAT('".$pass."', '".$uid."')) WHERE user_id = '".$uid."'");
}
?>
```

Comment: Ok this is fine. But how do I do it automatically? Without knowing the user ids to update. It should happen for every user already inserted in the users table. Since I do not know the exact user IDs, I need a way to do it for each user already in that table. Is there a way doing this with a Loop? Or something else? Thanks

Comment: yes but I think that already does it automatically? It takes user_id automatically from the row?

Comment: I added the loop, so try it if you want.

Comment: Because DiegoP asked loop I made it. It´s not nice to mark -1 for just trying to help.